# Duvida insert MySQL

Tags: mysql, sintaxe, sql-insert

Bom dia,
 Estou tentando fazer um insert,mais esta dando erro e parece ser no campo hora,poderiam me ajudar identificar o que esta errado:
 Segue o insert e o erro.

```
INSERT INTO senhas 
                                                 (senha_id,
                                                  senha_setor_id,
                                                  senha_tipo_id,
                                                  senha_numero,
                                                  senha_data,
                                                  senha_hora)
                                          VALUES 
                                                 ('1',
                                                  '1',
                                                  '1',
                                                  '1',
                                                  '2016-03-01',
                                                  '10:03:00');
```

Segue o retorno:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 14  0.000 sec

Os campos são:

```
senha_id        = int (11) 
senha_setor_id  = int (11) 
senha_tipo_id   = int (11)
senha_numero    = int (11) 
senha_data      = date 
senha_hora      = time
```

Como indicado por nosso colega @jbueno foram retiradas as '' dos campos int.

```
INSERT INTO senhas
                                             (senha_id,
                                              senha_setor_id,
                                              senha_tipo_id,
                                              senha_numero,
                                              senha_data,
                                              senha_hora)
                                      VALUES 
                                             ('',
                                              1,
                                              1,
                                              1,
                                              '2016-03-01',
                                              '10:03:00');
```

Comment: Você testou essa consulta no phpmyadmin ou workbench? parece que esse insert da pergunta não é o mesmo que foi testado.

Comment: @rray Você viu que o erro mostra uma aspa dupla (ou duas aspas simples) `[...]  syntax to use near ''`? Realmente parece que esse não é o `insert` que está sendo testado.

Comment: @jbueno o insert da pergunta está certo mesmo com aspas simples(se o valor for númerico ele é convertido), pra mim são duas aspas simples juntas ou seja um valor vazio. Também acho que o insert com problema é outro.

Comment: Pois é @rray, eu não fazia ideia que o MySQL convertia os valores, mas testei por curiosidade e deu certo. Isso que me fez pensar que o `insert` com problema é outro...

Comment: Verifica se a Foreign Key (FK) existe mesmo nas outras tabelas.

Comment: Pode marcar a resposta do jbueno como aceita, o sinal de verde significa que o problema foi resolvido, se tiver alguma dúvida pode ver, [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Answer (score 3):

Você está inserindo todos os campos como `varchar`.

Seu `insert` deve ficar assim

```
INSERT INTO senhas 
     (senha_id,
      senha_setor_id,
      senha_tipo_id,
      senha_numero,
      senha_data,
      senha_hora)
VALUES 
     (1,
      1,
      1,
      1,
      STR_TO_DATE('01, 03, 2016','%d,%m,%Y'),
      STR_TO_DATE('10:03:00','%h:%i:%s'));
```

Comment: Continua: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13 0.000 sec

Comment: Você está com a database selecionada?

Comment: Acabei de testar, o seu insert não está errado. O problema é outro.

Comment: sim,estou com a base selecionada

Comment: @OtacioBarbosa O `insert` da pergunta realmente está igual ao que está sendo testado?

Comment: consegui,deu certo,vou complementar na pergunta

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: @jbueno Testando a tabela do nosso amigo e o seu insert, percebi que houve um erro ao executar seu insert por conta do a na palavra '10:03:00a' e quando retirado funcionou normal... não seria o caso de editar sua resposta ?

Comment: @LucasAugusto Erro de digitação, mas, de qualquer forma, minha resposta não está correta, como (bem) pontuado pelo rray o MySQL faz a conversão automática dos valores...